# Why is the word "for" missing in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, headlinese

> A Saudi Arabian person arrested uploading abuse video.

I saw this line in some NEWS Channels scrolling. I am pretty sure word "**for**" is missing.

Why there is no "for" used in between **arrested** and **uploading** ?

Comment: This is not idiomatic English, even for a news channel.  Newspaper  English might read "Saudi Arabian arrested for abuse video", but as written I can only guess it's either an error or written by a non-native speaker. For example, "abused video" would mean that the **video** was abused, not the video contains abuse footage.

Comment: @Andrew **abused** changed to **abuse**.

Comment: Now the question is: what did you _really_ see on this news channel crawl? If you're reproducing this from memory, and you just remembered that the word was _abuse_ instead of _abused_, perhaps you also forgot the _for_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns an inaccurately remembered news channel crawl on an unknown news channel.

Comment: @user33250  Even with that change, it's not really a normal "news headline".  The "for" would not be left out, unless the structure of the sentence was different, for example "Saudi arrested after videoing police abuse."  If you could show us the actual headline, we could probably give you a better answer.

Comment: A Saudi Arabian person arrested uploading abuse video.
means
A Saudi Arabian person, (who is) uploading abuse video, (is) arrested.

Comment: A news crawl is no different than headlines, and you shouldn't try to apply normal grammar rules to them. In headlinese, space is often the issue. In a news crawl, you need to get the relevant words out there before they scroll off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because the missing word is "while", not "for".

"While" is often dropped in this context, often but not only in newswriting.

> He was approached walking down Fifth Avenue.

Of course, we would need to see more context to verify this.

If he was arrested while uploading the video but for other things (e.g. previously distributing materials), the sentence is natural.

If he was arrested both for and while uploading the video, it's an awkward way to say it.

And as the others have said in this thread, if he was arrested for uploading and *not* at the same time as he was doing it, it's simply an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the word "for" is missing. The reason for this is likely that news channels have limited space to put headlines, and shortening a scrolling headline can make it easier to read as it scrolls quickly across the screen. The channel made a decision to make the headline easier to read, at the expense of proper grammar.

It is also possible that this is a grammatical error by whoever wrote the headline

Comment: As written the sentence is not idiomatic, even for "headline" English.  Yes, news channels leave out words, but not those words, and why leave out "for" but include the extraneous "person"?

Comment: @Andrew Removing "person" might cause issues with viewers, as leaving out the word "person" might be seen as dehumanizing a group of people.  (i.e. "Jews", "Blacks" have historically been used as derogatory terms by racist people, while "Jewish people" or "Black people" have far less derogatory connotations) -- **Disclaimer: I don't mean to offend anyone with the given examples, I am just trying to make a point

Comment: In a different context, perhaps.  There's nothing derogatory about "Saudi Arabian" -- it's just a nationality.  Although "Saudi" by itself is often sufficient, or "Saudi national" as a contrast to the many guest workers who live there.

Comment: If you search for ["person arrested" headline](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22person+arrested%22+headline&t=ffab&ia=web) almost all of them use a preposition: "arrested for", "arrested on charges", "arrested after". I see lots of non-standard abbreviations and mangled phrases in news tickers, so I think the moral of the story is to not count on them even for proper "headlinese".